# unable to start cluster (mcm) mysql cluster management on linux vms

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

**Problem statement**
unable to start the cluster with firewall started on all vms.
when im starting the cluster it is able to start data node and management node but not mysqld and api nodes.

NOTE: im able to start cluster with firewalld stopped

Tried attempts:
added 1862, 18620 and 1186 ports firewalld and restarted the firewalld

**cluster defination**

```
vm1(data node)
1 data node
vm2(management node + mysqld)
1 management node 
1 mysqld
10+ api nodes
```

**some ERROR log**

```
2024-03-14T09:57:54.641994Z 0 [System] [MY-010865] [NDB] connection[0], NodeID: 146, no storage nodes connected (timed out)
2024-03-14T09:57:55.890727Z 0 [System] [MY-010865] [NDB] connection[1], NodeID: 146, no storage nodes connected (timed out)
2024-03-14T09:57:57.138724Z 0 [System] [MY-010865] [NDB] connection[2], NodeID: 147, no storage nodes connected (timed out)
2024-03-14T09:57:58.388321Z 0 [System] [MY-010865] [NDB] connection[3], NodeID: 148, no storage nodes connected (timed out)
2024-03-14T09:57:58.389031Z 0 [System] [MY-010866] [NDB] Binlog: Starting...
2024-03-14T09:57:58.389521Z 2 [System] [MY-010866] [NDB] Binlog: Started
2024-03-14T09:57:58.389552Z 2 [System] [MY-010866] [NDB] Binlog: Setting up
2024-03-14T09:57:58.389878Z 2 [System] [MY-010866] [NDB] Binlog: Setup completed
2024-03-14T09:57:58.389892Z 2 [System] [MY-010866] [NDB] Binlog: Wait for server start
2024-03-14T09:57:58.389901Z 0 [System] [MY-010866] [NDB] Index Stat: Starting...
2024-03-14T09:57:58.389946Z 0 [System] [MY-010866] [NDB] Index Stat: Wait for server start
2024-03-14T09:57:58.390324Z 0 [System] [MY-010866] [NDB] Metadata: Starting...
2024-03-14T09:57:58.390365Z 0 [System] [MY-010866] [NDB] Metadata: Wait for server start
2024-03-14T09:57:58.400743Z 0 [System] [MY-010865] [NDB] ndbinfo prefix: './ndbinfo/ndb@0024'
2024-03-14T09:57:58.590289Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2024-03-14T09:57:58.599903Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
```

any help, bcz I'm trying to so solve it from few hours no use
thank you

Comment: Port 1186 is the default management node port. What is port 1862 and 18620? Is ServerPort configured for data nodes?

Comment: @MauritzSundell it is mcm, one more layer of mysql cluster. both 1862 and 18620 are using by mcm

Answer (score 0):

All API nodes including mysqld and also data nodes will also connect to *all* data nodes.

By default data nodes will listen on random ports which the other nodes will find out by asking the management node. This will not work easily with firewalls.

Instead one should configure ServerPort for the data nodes and open that port in the firewall.

See [MySQL Reference Manual | Defining NDB Cluster Data Nodes | ServerPort](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#ndbparam-ndbd-serverport)